# Showing a solution is not bounded

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I must show that if $a(t) \in \mathbb{C}[0, \infty]$ and is a bounded function and if $\phi(t)$ is a non-trivial solution to $y'' + a(t) y = 0$ satisfying $\phi(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$ , then the above differential equation has a solution which is not bounded over $[0, \infty)$.

I am not sure how to approach this problem / where to begin. Can someone please give some assistance regarding this?

Comment: This is sonewhat confusing.  Is $a(t)$ the coefficient of $y$ in the equation $ y'' + a(t)y = 0$ and the solution as well? Please clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: @RobertLewis I have edited my post to show the correct question. Sorry for the typos I had in the original.